# Error trying to connect to socket

Tags: python, sockets, http, networking

I am learning how to use python to connect to a socket via HTTP protocol and retrieve an URL. Can someone assist to point out where I might have gone wrong?

Python Code:

```
# Networking
## Connect to a Socket
import socket
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80)) # Host, Port Number

cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/intro-short.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while TRUE:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if (len(data)<1):
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysock.close()
```

I run the program on Windows 10 Command Prompt:

```
C:\Users\Kane\Desktop>python networking.py
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "networking.py", line 7, in <module>
    mysock.connect(('data.pr4.org', 80)) # Host, Port Number
  File "C:\Users\Kane\Anaconda2\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Thanks.

Comment: is "data.pr4.org" a valid server to connect to ?

Comment: In able to know the real error ask Python what type of exception that is: by a try & catch statement with printing type(exception)

Comment: Apart from using a hostname which cannot be resolved by DNS the HTTP request is not a valid HTTP request since it includes the URL instead only the path and also misses the Host header which is needed today in most cases even though HTTP/1.0 does not strictly require it. If you really want to use the HTTP protocol directly instead of a higher level library which does this for you then please don't guess the protocol but study the written standard or at least look very close at existing HTTP traffic done by properly implemented clients.

Comment: @coder data.pr4e.org is a valid server. I have amended the code.

Comment: @FadySaad How should I write the try and catch statement in this case? Could you share some code snippets?

Comment: @ Steffen Ullrich Thanks for your suggestion. I was learning using the code snippet that was provided by an online course. Would definitely appreciate it if you can point me to the right resources.

Comment: This is a network configuration error, not something in your code. Try pinging the server or tracerouting it.

Comment: Your code works fine (except that `TRUE` should be `True`) on my machine.

Comment: The error in your post shows that the hostname you provide can't be resolved and thus can't be reached for some reason. Can you ping it? Also do you use any kind of proxy ? Try also by providing its ip instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that @t.m.adam was right.

The code works fine except that TRUE should be True.

It could have been a host or server problem earlier. I shall delete the question if others can get the same output below:

```
C:\Users\Kane\Desktop>python networking.py
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 17 Sep 2017 00:12:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Sat, 13 May 2017 11:22:22 GMT
ETag: "1d3-54f6609240717"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 467
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain
```